# Java: How to pass a class to a function for instantiation

Tags: java, templates, generics

Please forgive my ignorance, but I wasn't able to find an answer elsewhere.

I have the following code:

```
int value = 5;
Strategy s = new Strategy(convert(value));
mainClass.setStuff(s, value);
```

The Strategy is initialized with a number that is based on a conversion of "value".
The mainClass uses the unconverted "value".

What I would like to do is to simplify this by giving mainClass only the information which Strategy to use and with which unconverted value, whereupon mainClass should do the instantiation and initialization of the Strategy and process the value.

In C++ this would be possible with a template:

```
int value = 5;
mainClass.setStuff<Strategy>(value);
```

Can I make this work in Java somehow? It doesn't seem to work with generics as unlike C++, Java cannot infer the type of the argument, so I can't initialize Strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `setStuff` method signature to `public <T extends Strategy> ReturnType setStuff(Class<T> clazz, int value)`. Then you can [find the correct constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) and create your [new instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: But wouldn't that mean passing an object to setStuff? So in other words, I would need to instantiate Strategy, pass it to setStuff, which in turn would instantiate it again for use? I don't see the advantage here.

Comment: @Cerno No, you are passing the `Class` of the object, not the object itself. If you wanted to pass in `Strategy`'s class, you would call `setStuff(Strategy.class, value)`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll give that one a go.

Comment: Okay, I tried and but I have to admit, I don't like it much. For one, the code correctness is only checked at runtime, which is a no-go when coding for the Android platform. The other issue is that it seems pretty ugly to me. The code is massive since I have to handle six exceptions. I thank you for the solution and as far as I can see it's the only way to do what I want in Java, but I was hoping for something simpler, more elegant. As it is, I guess the previous way of doing it was better.

Comment: @Cerno: See also [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).